# Civicrm Rebux PHP limit?

Tags: reports

I have installed [Civicrm Rebux](https://civicrm.org/blog/ypranay/introducing-civirebux-native-report-building-extension-for-civicrm) on our test system

This seemed to install fine, no errors reported - however when clicking on it (under reports) I get a white screen of death).

On checking error logs I see this report

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4104 bytes) in MYDOMMAIN.COM/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 1372\n', referer: http://MYDOMMAIN.COM/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm

So it looks like it hit the PHP memory_limit of 128MB.

I upped the memory_limit to 256MB (the highest I can go to) and then got the message:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) in MYDOMAIN.COM/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 1372\n', referer: http://MYDOMAIN.COM/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm

Any suggestions?